# Form validation: if there is errors don't animate the accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin on the [awsAccordion](http://code.anotherwebstorm.com/apps/awsaccordion/). I want to open the next tab of my accordion after the validation is run without errors.

This is what i did: http://jsfiddle.net/vqL4p/7/

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        field1: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        field2: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator){ //if there is error
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        var message = (errors == 1) ? "One of your groups won't validate." : "Neither of your groups will validate.";
        alert(message);
        $('dt').unbind('click'); //if there is error remove click on the tab
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        alert('valid form submitted'); 
        return false;
        }
});

$('dt').click(
    function(e){
    $("#myform").valid();
});
```

The problem is that the unbind click `$('dt').unbind('click');` works only after tab is closed and the next is opened. Do you know a way to solve this problem?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to unbind the click event, instead you just need to stop the propagation and prevent rest of the handlers from being executed using [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/). And check for the validity of the form inside the click event using `!$("#myform").valid()`.

Try:

```
     $('dt').click(function(e){
       if(!$("#myform").valid()){ //Check if form is valid or not
           e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //stop rest of the handlers from being executed
       };
     });


     $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            var message = (errors == 1) ? "Validated." : "Error! the field is required";
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            alert('valid form submitted'); 
        }
    });


    $("#accordion1").awsAccordion({
            type:"horizontal",
            cssAttrsHor:{
                ulWidth:"responsive",
                liWidth:50,
                liHeight:300
            },
            startSlide:1,
            openOnebyOne:true,
            classTab:"active",
            slideOn:"click",
            autoPlay:false,
            autoPlaySpeed:500
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sJnsq/)**